# iTunes do not connect to iTunes Store anymore

Tags: itunes, windows, macos

This started to happen some days ago, but it's pretty annoying, my podcasts aren't been updating too.
When I click in iTunes Store it just show 'accessing itunes store' (the loading bar) and just keep this like forever.
I already try to remove iTunes completely like it says here:http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1923

And here: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/23959/completely-remove-itunes-and-other-apple-software-from-a-windows-computer/

But still with same error, any adivce ?

Here it's all the programs that are installed in my computer now:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SeMnJ.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TuYpU.png

My computer is a :
DELL Optplex 790
Windows 7 x64
8gb memory RAM

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution [here](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1263609)

> Try this folks - it has just solved my problem - iTunes 10.5 is
>   running perfectly and only using about 50% CPU.
>
> Start --> Programs --> Accessories (Right Click on Command Prompt) -->
>   Run as Administrator then type in: Netsh winsock reset Hit enter,
>   restart PC, open iTunes, go to Store
>
> Alternatively you can use the 'Run' icon just to the right of 'All
>   Programs' when you click on start, past in Netsh winsock reset and
>   enter.
>
> Hopefully it works for you too.
>
> For further reference material on this have a look at:
>   http://support.microsoft.com/kb/299357

Comment: this solution is also work for me, for the `netsh winsock reset` command part. I don't even have to restart the PC nor have to start the iTunes as Administrator.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your internet connection allows connection with iTunes (maybe some kind of firewall...) and is it fast enough?
Some details of your computer would also be nice

Comment: I'm pretty sure @vrwim, that my firewall is not the problem, I turn off the firewall and even uninstall my antivirus, but still with the problem.

Comment: I also update my post with more information with what is running in my computer, could you please take a look of that ?